# castle windsor abstract class

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, castle

i have this abstract class that contains an implementation. and it is inherited from this `class ConfigurationXmlFile : BaseConfigurationUtilities`.
How could register implementation in castle windsor?.

```
public abstract  class BaseConfigurationUtilities
{
    public abstract List<T> GetListaParametriConfigurazione<T>(string nomeConfigurazione);

    protected List<T> GetConfigurationsFromString<T>(string stringaConfigurazione)
    {
        List<T> toReturn = new List<T>();

        //se non c'è niente allora ritorno lista vuota
        if (stringaConfigurazione.Length == 0)
            return toReturn;

        //se c'è un solo elemento, quindi NON c'è il separatore di matricole ;
        if (!stringaConfigurazione.Contains(";"))
        {
            T toAdd = (T)Convert.ChangeType(stringaConfigurazione, typeof(T));
            toReturn.Add(toAdd);
            return toReturn;
        }

        //se c'è piu di un elemento 
        List<string> listaConfigurazioni = stringaConfigurazione.Split(';').ToList();
        foreach (string configurazione in listaConfigurazioni)
        {
            T toAdd = (T)Convert.ChangeType(configurazione, typeof(T));
            toReturn.Add(toAdd);
        }

        return toReturn;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some details to your question. What does the constructor of `ConfiguationXmlFile` look like? More importantly, what abstraction (if any) does the application expect, `BaseConfigurationUtilities` or some interface?

Comment: excuse me now everything is ok, i had an error because i injected the implementation in the Index action ad not in the Constructor.